# Is there any way to monitor access of files in c#?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I tried using FileSystemWatcher and NotifyFilter (using lastaccess)..

But it didn't work...

i want is that when a file will be opened either text or image or anything it should fire an event.

Thank you.

Comment: You should consider posting your attempted code here and instead of saying "it didn't work...", posting specifically WHY it didn't work. We cannot do much to help you otherwise.

Comment: In what way did `FileSystemWatcher` not work?  MSDN seems to indicate that it should indeed raise an event if a file changes.

Comment: It works perhaps you are not setting up your filter and events properly.. post what code you have so we may be able to assist.. I've never had issues with it working ..

Comment: FileSystemWatcher notifies you about modifications. If you want to monitor access (file being opened), you need to use a filesystem filter driver. You need to either write one or use our CallbackFilter.

Comment: Sorry guys i should have posted code...

Answer (score 4):

I wish you would post code, but the following snippet works fine:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           FileSystemWatcher fs = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Temp");
           fs.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fs_Changed);
           fs.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Changed);
           while (true)
           { 
              // Just keep console window open so you 
              // can see events when you change a file
           }
        }

  static void  fs_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File {0} changed", e.Name);
        }
```